# How to change the thickness of the line drawn using System.Drawing.Pen?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have drawn the below icon by using Graphics.DrawLine() method.
[image]

The problem is, changing the width of the Pen from **1.0f** to **1.5f** doesn't show any difference in the thickness of the line.

Setting the width of the pen to **1.6f** draws the line more darker.

I need to draw the line slightly darker than the 1st one and lighter than the last one.

I have tried to set Graphics.SmoothingMode property as given below.

```
graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
```

This doesn't show any difference. I don't know whether I have to set any other 
property.

Kindly share your valuable suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Mohanram Anbukkarasu.

Comment: There's a bug with pen widths less then 1.5, which has been in GDI+ for years. A possible workaround is to draw the lines in a lighter colour instead.

Comment: You could set the transparency different for every line.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I can't able to decide the color of the line. I need to draw the line by using the color provided by the corresponding team.

Comment: You could also try drawing everything to 2× the required size on an off-screen `Bitmap` object, and then resize it to 50%.

Answer (score 0):

The page unit is Pixels, so the value (1.5f) is internally casted to INT (via method **Math.Round()**).
1.5 is casted to **1**

1.6 is casted to **2**

There is no value between 1 and 2.

**This requirement is not achievable.**

Comment: if it will cast internally, why Microsoft exposes a float?

Comment: But, I can able to see the difference between 2.0f and 2.5f.